# How should I approach my first attempt at displaying dynamic data on a web page?

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

For context, **so far I've successfully built a series of stylized web pages in html**, all through HostGator. I'm wanting to now step things up and add dynamic content.

I figured I would start small (read: pathetically easy for the vast majority of you) and **try displaying a random quote every time I reload the html page** (perhaps then adding a button that then allows me to grab and display a new one). At first I figured I'd pull text data stored on a mySQL database (again, built through HostGator via their 'phpMyAdmin' application) and display it on my html page. But googling how to do that has only led me to question that approach.

**The problem is I'm struggling with not knowing what I don't know, and as such, not knowing what to google for guidance.**

My having picked up context clues as I've wandered the net have me now realizing there's multiple approaches to this. At the very least, AJAX or PHP/Database.

I know nothing about PHP or the AJAX methodology. My layman's understanding is that they're quite different and take me down different routes of skill development.

So, **I'm wondering if anyone could advise me on the right approach to take as a beginner who wants to maintain momentum and continue to play and experiment with more complex and dynamic concepts**. I'd rather learn something more difficult if it means it sends me down a pathway with more potential to play around and learn.

And finally, if you could possibly point me towards learning resources for that approach? It's difficult to find a straight forward tutorial for something that has so many solutions/approaches.

Thank you SO much for any help/advice!

Comment: You beter search for some tutorials on google, I dont think this is a site for starter. you need to know atleast basic usage of any programing language to ask a question here. I recomend you to start with php pdo its easy to learn and easy to use see here for almost all you need https://phpdelusions.net/pdo for database connections and queries. and after learning main programing language you can work with ajax.

Comment: Believe it or not I've a decent amount of experience with C# and even a bit of python at this point, but nothing that would aid in this regard. Web development is entirely new to me and so any point in the right direction makes a huge difference. Thanks so much for this link. Pouring through it now

Comment: Start with some high-level (less than 10 mins) videos on youtube explaining things like architecture. Dynamic content driven site processes have change quite a bit since the PHP days and you dont want to spend time learning older methods. Research MEAN stack or better yet, start with the concept of a 'stack' developer and go from there. After you feel more confident - dont go any further without first learning to use the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: @DataGuy Thanks so much for this. Buzzwords like this help me find learning resources. I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: I really now the situation. Started with Ruby without a clue, then tried Jekyll + CSS/HTML, not telling you to do that. My tipps are simple: I am reading a lot of articles about different topics as well as reading posts on Stackoverflow on a certain topic to see if can understand the topic. The best thing is to try things out on your own. Do some tutorials, either written or in form of (youtube) videos. The MEAN stack and architecture indicated by @DataGuy are good, but it depends on your interests as well as focus, E.g. I want to start React/Typescript. Follow interesting and unknown topics.

Comment: If you are familiar with Python, why not start with Python - perhaps a microframework like Bottle?  But before that if web pages are what you are interested in.  Simple HTML and HTTP, and a sprinkle of Javascript is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not that offay with Javascript.  Here is an approach that uses a javascript list, with a random item chosen.  Everytime you refresh the page, a quote is picked at random and injected into paragraph with the id of quote.

The nice thing about this approach is that the page can be effectively static/cached.

If your quote list is long, you could pull it in via a http request (search for JSON xmlHttpRequest).
I'll leave you to work out how to add a button to get another quote.

This example is a good starting point.  If this is sloppy javascript please feel free to edit, but try not to loose the brevity of this solution.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var quotes = [
                "There's theory and then there's application. They don't always jibe.",
                "That man's in a lot of trouble.",
                "What can I say? To us it's a slime pit, but to them it's home."
            ];

            function get_random_quote() {
                var randomItem = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];

                return randomItem;
            }

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
                document.getElementById('quote').textContent = get_random_quote(); 
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='quote'></p>
    </body>
</html>
```